# react-day-picker: Set date inside navbarElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-day-picker

I have a component that uses the `react-day-picker` component. I wan't to have a datepicker where the year and the month can be increased or decreased seperatly.
So I've overwritten the `navbarElement` (as you can see in the last line). In the arrow function `handleNextYearClick` the year should be increased by 1. But how can I access and set the `date` from the parent Component `DayPicker`. I can only call `onNextClick` which just increases the month+1.

```
export interface IDatePickerNavbarProps {
    date?: Date,
    nextMonth?: Date,
    previousMonth?: Date,
    localeUtils?: any,
    locale?: string,
    onNextClick?: () => {}
}

export interface IDatePickerNavbarState {

}

class DatePickerNavBar extends Component<IDatePickerNavbarProps, IDatePickerNavbarState> {

    constructor(props: IDatePickerNavbarProps) {
        super(props);
    }

    handleNextMonthClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        this.props.onNextClick();
    }

    handleNextYearClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        // How to set the new date => current date + 1 year
        // I am only able to call this.props.onNextClick() but that does 
        // +1 only month count
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={Styles.DayPickerSelectBox}>
                <div className={Styles.DayPickerNavbarYear}>
                    year:
                    <span>last</span>  -  <span onClick={this.handleNextYearClick}>next</span>
                </div>
                <div className={Styles.DayPickerNavbarMonth}>
                    month:
                    <span>last</span>  -  <span onClick={this.handleNextMonthClick}>next</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

... this is my code inside the `render()` method in my main date-picker component...

```
<DayPicker navbarElement={<DatePickerNavBar />} captionElement={<DatePickerCaption />} />
```

Do not feel disturbed by the typescript notation.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the current month it is not exposed to `navbarElement`:

http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPicker#navbarElement

It has `previousMonth` tough :)

A `month` prop will be added in the next release: https://github.com/gpbl/react-day-picker/pull/552

```
navbarElement={
  (month) => <DatePickerNavBar currentMonth={month} />
}
```